# How to set git global config in smartgit

Tags: git, smartgit

I need to set this config for my smartgit:  `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` for my SmartGit. How do I do it?

Need some guidance on how to do this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SmartGit is invoking command line Git for all relevant Git operations. Hence, if you are using command line client to set this config value, exactly as you wrote it, you are all set.

Comment: where do i change so that i can type this?

Comment: Type in your `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` on the command line/terminal, as you would do without SmartGit.

Comment: I tried this using the git shell and can see that setting changed in the config but smartgit still errors. Is there an additional step for this?